# To sum values in a column based on date in another column and group it

Tags: sql

I have the following table in a database. I want to be able to get the sum of the value column but only based on the date.

```
+-------+---------+------------+
| ID    | value   | date       |
+-------+---------+------------+
|   1   |   3     | 2011-12-22 |
|   1   |   2     | 2011-12-22 |
|   1   |   4     | 2011-12-22 |
|   1   |   2     | 2012-01-01 |
+-------+---------+------------+
```

which should be

```
+-------+---------+------------+
| ID    | value   | date       |
+-------+---------+------------+
|   1   |   9     | 2011-12-22 |
|   1   |   2     | 2012-01-01 |
+-------+---------+------------+
```

can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

```
Select id,sum(`value`) `value` , DATE(`date`) from table_name group by DATE(`date`);
```

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu They are keywords with special meanings . You shouldn't use the keywords as identifiers.

Comment: This query gives me the same result as original table

Comment: Date has time stamp associated with it and i have to sum up based on the dates

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ID, SUM(value), date FROM table_name GROUP BY date;
```

Comment: no luck :( it is giving me error missing expression. I am using it in oracle